# Workflow Manager 1.0- SQL Login Password Reset

Tags: sql-server, workflow, powershell-3.0

I have installed Workflow Manager 1.0 (Refresh). The topology I using is a single Workflow Manager server (VM) with a separate single Azure SQL Server (both within a single Azure subscription). I have a need to perform a Password reset for the SQL Login used that connects to the Workflow Manager related Databases. What would be the sequential procedure in Workflow Manager to change the connection strings for Workflow Manager 1.0 and Service Bus 1.1? Currently there are active workflows so a re-install including dropping existing Workflow databases is not an option.

After resetting the Azure SQL Login password I have run the Update-WFDatabasePassword cmdlet in PowerShell with the following results: 
**VERBOSE: [1/28/2016 4:10:44 PM]: Password for the SQL database has been updated successfully.**

However, when running Get-WFFarmStatus or Stop-WFHost cmdlet I am getting the following error: **..System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904 Login failed for user  'wfuser'..**

Does anyone know which steps to follow to after a Resetting the password for SQL Login used in Workflow Manager?

Comment: Did you also run `Update-WFHost` run on all hosts joined in the farm to update password references stored on individual hosts, as per [this documentation on the MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713558(v=azure.10).aspx)?